# Select data from two table as one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similar tables and want to give a result from two tables with one query with a result like one table ( rows as tandem and order with time )

***MyTable1:***

```
time    name    Comment
-------------------------
45      asd     testasd
49      gas     testgas
50      has     testhas
96      bag     testbag
```

***MyTable2:***

```
time    name    Comment
-------------------------
48      hjasf   bigasd
54      adg     biggas
65      zxx     bighas
115     cxx     bobbag
131     xxb     bobhas
```

***RESULT:***

```
time    name    Comment
-------------------------
45      asd     testasd
48      hjasf   bigasd
49      gas     testgas
50      has     testhas
54      adg     biggas
65      zxx     bighas
96      bag     testbag
115     cxx     bobbag
131     xxb     bobhas
```

I try to do it but don't know , I must use JOIN or UNION or ... ?

Comment: I edit the question to solved , because i can't select accept a answer below 15minutes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `UNION ALL` (*ALL - to allow duplicates.*)

```
SELECT time, name, Comment FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT time, name, Comment FROM table2
ORDER BY time
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad64b/1)

The `UNION` command is used to select related information from two tables, much like the JOIN command. However, when using the UNION command all selected columns need to be of the same data type. With UNION, only distinct values are selected.

The `UNION ALL` command is equal to the UNION command, except that UNION ALL selects all values.

The difference between Union and Union all is that Union all will not eliminate duplicate rows, instead it just pulls all rows from all tables fitting your query specifics and combines them into a table.

- [Difference Between Union vs. Union All](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/)

The output will look like this,

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ TIME ║ NAME  ║ COMMENT ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║   45 ║ asd   ║ testasd ║
║   48 ║ hjasf ║ bigasd  ║
║   49 ║ gas   ║ testgas ║
║   50 ║ has   ║ testhas ║
║   54 ║ adg   ║ biggas  ║
║   65 ║ zxx   ║ bighas  ║
║   96 ║ bag   ║ testbag ║
║  115 ║ cxx   ║ bobbag  ║
║  131 ║ xxb   ║ bobhas  ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

If both tables have the same number of fields, you could use this:

```
SELECT * from MyTable1
UNION ALL
SELECT * from MyTable2
ORDER BY time
```

UNION ALL will select all rows of the first query, combined with all of the rows of the second query. If you need to remove duplicates you should use UNION instead of UNION ALL. The ORDER BY clause will order the resulting rows by time.

See documentation of [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) clause here.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Use select statements with union all in between to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION ALL as follows:

```
SELECT `time`, `name`, `Comment` FROM `MyTable1`
UNION ALL
SELECT `time`, `name`, `Comment` FROM `MyTable2`
```

To order by time try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT `time`, `name`, `Comment` FROM `MyTable1`
UNION ALL
SELECT `time`, `name`, `Comment` FROM `MyTable2`
) AS `Result` ORDER BY `time` ASC
```